# Log form data in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, logging

I'm using CommonsRequestLoggingFilter to log the incoming REST API requests in a Spring Boot 3.0 project.
I have a HTML form that submits a POST method with form data and another POST method that submits JSON data.

CommonsRequestLoggingFilter does log the request body for the POST method with JSON data.

If I use form data i.e. if enctype = application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data, the request body does not get logged. I'm not expecting the file content to be logged, but I do want the other attributes to be logged.

Has anybody come across this issue and is there an out of the box solution for this?